# Xcode update to 4.3.2 messes up my certificates

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, certificate, xcode4.3

Last week I finished an app and submitted to apple store from Xcode 4

Now I updated to Xcode 4.3.2 and for the same app I'm getting:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Then after a few searches and tests I realized two things:

- My certificate expiration date is set to May 02, 2012, which is weird. But I dont think its a big deal because I just uploaded my app last week
- When I get inside the organizer and check my iPhone 4S provisioning profiles they are all yellow. So I deleted them.

This second made me go to the Provisioning Portal again and check my registered phones.  realized that my new iPhone 4S is not there.. but when I got back to the Organizer, the "use this for development" button is not there anymore. Probably because I tried that on the Xcode 4.

Anyway, how do I renew my certificate so it refreshes the expiration date?
And more important how do I add my new phone to the portal? Just set the id and name and refresh organizer?

Comment: You can download the certificate again.

Comment: The certificate is not a problem I guess, but anyway I downloaded again and its expiration date is still from my "last" year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to clear all the certificates and redownload everything.